# Ito Formula for Stochastic Integral

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

Suppose I have $$dS_t  = \mu(S_t,t) dt + \sigma(S_t,t)dW_t$$
What would be the process satisfying the following process of $y_t$? 
$$y_t = \int_0^t S_u du + \int_0^t S_u dW_u$$

I'm not quite sure about differentiating $y_t$. The following is what I did
$$\frac{\partial y_t}{\partial S_t} =dt +dW_t $$
and 
$$\frac{\partial^2 dy_t}{\partial dS_t^2} = 0$$

Are these right? Then Ito's Formula gives
$$dy_t = (dt+dW_t)dS_t = \sigma(S_t,t)dt $$

But this feels wrong. Can anyone helps me with it please?

Comment: Are you missing a $\partial_t y_t$?

Comment: @Kenneth Chen : well as long as your process S is well defined (i.e. the sde has a solution) your process $y_t$ is correctly defined and the differential form is simply : $dy_t=S_tdt+S_tdW_t$ no more, no less. Your formulas are certainly all wrong. Best regards

Comment: @TheBridge Thanks! I've noted that.